# I can't convert the image to Base 64

Tags: java, android

I do not understand why it marks me in red as an error. In both private String
The error is in this line : **return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)** , in **encodeToString** y **DEFAULT**

As error in both private strings it shows me this:

C:\Users\juan_\AndroidStudioProjects\OttavisHotelCafe\app\src\main\java\com\juanrichard\ottavishotelcafe\MainActivity_Registrar_Habitacion_H.java:488: error: cannot find symbol

```
  return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable DEFAULT
  location: class Base64
```

---

```
private String GetStringImagen(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);
    byte[ ]imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

---

```
private String GetStringImagen(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String str = "";
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte [] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    try {
        str = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Which `Base64` class are you using? Are you sure you're not declaring your own one somewhere? If you could provide a [mcve] that would help. (I'd also recommend following Java naming conventions, as an aside - and stopping swallowing exceptions.)

Comment: `java.util.Base64`  does not contain 'DEFAULT'

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `DEFAULT` and not `NO_WRAP`? Probably import `android.util.Base64` too.

Comment: You can't *compile your code* that converts an image to base-64. Not the same thing as your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Java project, from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-, you don't give a second argument for a default encoding using the ISO-8859-1 charset. So, try using

```
return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes);
```

OR, for Android,
From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64,
you can put second argument as DEFAULT. So, try using

```
return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, DEFAULT);
```

as your return statement.